# Operation System Clone from a Motherboard to Another

Tags: windows, memory, cpu, motherboard

Lately we had an idea with my Family of building a Super Computer from Scratch. So while we were planning on building our setup, one idea came to my head that it seems possible but i want also your opinions.

Lets say that we have 2 ATX Motherboards and 1 MicroATX.

1. Motherboard Setup:

   - 1x ASUS Rampage Extreme Black Edition
   - 1x Intel Core i7 4960x
   - 4x GTX Titan
   - 8x 8GB 1866 Ram
2. Motherboard Setup:

   - 1x SuperMicro X9DRG-QF
   - 2x Intel Xeon E7-8890V2
   - 1x nVIDIA QUADRO K6000
   - 4x nVIDIA Tesla K40
   - 128 GB 1866 Ram

And imagine a Solid State Drive with a Switch connected to both of the MotherBoards

Can i edit & copy all the data of The first motherboard's RAM to The Other's to be able to continue operating my current Operation System after switching the SSD to the Second Motherboard, from the Second MotherBoard and vice versa?

Les say my "Switch Application" modifies everything the Kernel needs to believe nothing happend and continuing its operation from the same point the first motherboard stopped. (Changes on the Device List, CPU Cores, Drivers... etc)

Comment: Your question does not make a great deal of sense.

Comment: What part you did not understand to rephrase it?

Comment: Its not that clear what your trying to accomplish to be honest.  You want this mechanical switch to do what exactly?

Comment: Lets say that we have an application in our Operation System that takes every value from the RAM and Stores it into the hard drive. Also it takes the Kernel of the Operating System and stores it aswell to the hard drive. After that this application modifying every asset that is about the hardware and changing the values to fit for our Second Motherboard. After this this Application Puts the Computer to "Wait Mode" switching the HDD to the Second Motherboard Loading All the Data to the Ram and the Kernel to CPU, and sends a signal to change source of the Display on the Fly

Comment: and resume the state of the OS of the First Motherboard to the Other, working with our other Hardware

Comment: The problem with your idea is the following.  You won't have access to every value in memory, the operating system, won't allow it.

Comment: I can say something is bit possible because I am aware of how operating systems work, now you can write your own OS I suppose but that an entirely different thing

Comment: https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotos09/tech/full_papers/kozuch/kozuch_html/index.html

Comment: Why would you do that? What's the point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term 'super computer' implies a computer NOT made of off the shelf parts. This is not a supercomputer you are speaking of. As far as the SSD idea. You are missing several factors which are going to be impossible to overcome. First, an SSD is fast but it is nowhere near as fast as DDR3 RAM is (when you copy a 8GB file to your hard drive it still has time to pop up a dialog to show you the progress; your system would essentially be waiting those 10-20 seconds EACH RAM bus clock cycle; IOW 1833 million times per second [that's what 1833 mhz means] it'll need to wait 10-20 seconds; see the problem). Even if it was, there is something called latency which would bring this system to it's knees; this is why there is no such thing as an external RAM module. RAM NEEDS to be snappy; the latency this system would introduce would be unacceptable (and problematic for timing issues too). I think you'd be surprised to find out how much of the code on your machine is heavily dependent on the precise timing a short transmission distance affords RAM. Even if you somehow managed to get this to work (which you won't), an SSD has a limited number of write cycles so this type of workload would wear your SSD out as fast as is possible; it would destroy itself even faster but, lucky for your drive, it can only destroy itself so fast (see my first point).

The fact is that these are the exact same reasons that supercomputers are really an outdated way to upscale. These latency issues really cannot be worked around without redesigning the paradigm. The way we deal with these latency issue these days is by clustering. All a cluster is is a bunch of computers which can talk SLOWLY to each other. You probably already have this setup if both of those PCs are on the same network. Now to get those two PCs to work together is a programming challenge not a hardware engineering challenge.

**Update**

```
We can try to do this but it will take time, a lot of time. Everything is possible when you are aware of a System's Architecture. You can manipulate it in whatever way you want.
```

No, I'm sorry but if you knew the underlying arch then you wouldn't be asking this question in the first place because I've really just scratched the surface of why this will NEVER work. Do you plan to write a program which will sync the registers? The l2\l3 caches? How about one that'll ensure that each chip on your mobo is configured the same? Do you have any plan to ensure that the IRQ channels are being used identically? Or maybe you have a plan which is going to add physical components which are different between the two systems in real time? Is it going to automatically rewrite the driver software so that the same driver in memory is going to work on both machines? I'm sorry but you can't sit there and convince me that you are an expert when you haven't demonstrated that you have any awareness of (more less a way to overcome) any of these problems.

I'm sure at least one of you has used a hot swap drive before? If you have then you'd know that, in addition to what I've already mentioned, the whole process of disconnecting a drive and reconnecting it somewhere else is not even close to instantaneous. My PC boots in less than 15 seconds. That's about the same amount of time it'll take to get 8GB RAM transferred to another drive; then you're going to need to add another 7-8 seconds for the actual drive swap and finally you're going to need to read all that data back into RAM on the other PC. I *really* think a group of IT pros should understand this stuff right away.

OTOH, if you began looking at this from a perspective of solving a problem instead of inventing a new system you'd see that by using the network and changing the requirements to focus more on an actual problem you'd be able to get rid of practically ALL of the hardware issues (because others have already figured it out) and at the same time remove most of the data transfer lag (by not transferring any more data than is absolutely needed).

What I'm suggesting that you do is to not try to couple the machines together like you are wanting to do because it is never going to work. That isn't because I don't have the imagination to see it; it is because it really is not possible in the slightest. Instead, you should use your network because it is designed to do exactly what you need. You only need a way to get program inputs from one machine to the other and then transfer the output back when it finishes. As long as the problem can be broken down into discreet tasks this will work very well (which are the same limitations that CUDA has in the first place so nothing has changed here). I think you don't like this plan because it is too simple and you are like me and prefer a challenge. The problem is that what you are wanting to do is beyond challenging, it **is** impossible to do with the equipment you have.

If you really just want to make a system which works like this then it can be done. Just not with the hardware you are using. Go out and grab some commodity processors (such as those sold by Atmel or even ARM CPUs [the Raspberry Pi could work well for this]) and then design an arch from the ground up which is made to work like this. Also, when you do this, you're going to want to use RAM chips (not eeprom as is used in SSDs) because they are *much* faster (although, if you want it to be persistent you'd have to invent your own hybernation system which could very well use eeprom). Then you can physically wire all the CPUs to the same memory modules (meaning you'd get rid of the extra copy ops). Then it would be possible (if you can work out a good mechanism for giving each CPU it's own timeslice on the memory) but that is because you will not be trying to build it on top of another system which doesn't work this way at all.

-PEACE and GL

Comment: Hello and thank you for your report. I'm aware how a cluster works and this is not, what i intend to do. I also know about the latency but you got the whole idea wrong. Let me give you an example. Lets say I'm using the Computer with the First Motherboard, and suddenly i have the urge of creating something. So i open an application and this application puts the computer in a Kind of Wait mode.There's a screen and saying Please Waiting Changing System.In that time Everything from the RAM of the First Motherboard is getting stored as you said in the SSD, and then to the Second's Motherboard RAM.

Comment: That is not a proceedure that it will be done every like 1 sec or so. I wasnt talking about realtime stuff. I need a solution of pausing my Current Operation System state, and restoring it in another System. Just think it like it was a switch. Imagine having 2 computers running simultaneously and when you Turn the Switch monitor goes to the other computer and vice versa. Now Imagine having 2 computers running on the same drive. And the switch just copies everything from the first computer's ram to the other's.

Comment: Also since i dont really care about the Latency and the Delay i could use a SAS HDD for this Job (Writing RAM's Data) instead of using my SSD and reducing like you said its life.

Comment: Seriously, this is never going to work anyway like you are describing. You would be best served if you forget what you think you want to do and get yourself a few 10GBs NICs and a matching switch. That'll be faster than any SSD or HDD. As an added bonus, it'll actually work.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply @krowe. I Don't thing that TESLA can perform over network. We are a team of Software and Hardware Engineers in my Family. We can try to do this but it will take time, a lot of time. Everything is possible when you are aware of a System's Architecture. You can manipulate it in whatever way you want. Imagine the Alternative. A Background Boot on the Second Motherboard and the restoring of the windows state in the new booted  OS.

Comment: @Devian See the update.

Comment: Thank you for your time and update. In fact i have allready came up to these issues you mentioned and thats why im here, to hear different opinions. I'm stating my ideas and waiting a debate. Indeed i want a Challenge. The Setup we are building is a Challenge. We are trying to make a computer Suit to Everyone's needs. Gamer/Developer/Engineer/Scientist and so on. Designing our own Operation System in a way different Architecture than Windows/Unix using was an idea, died a long time ago. To Create such an operating system you need Many Developers, working on it every day.

Comment: Fortunately we have jobs, and we are working to make our living from them. And this project is just what we are planning to do on our free time. To Dedicate our selfs in order to create a new os and a new arch, would require to quit our jobs and families, to make a hole in the water. Modifying an OS would be less tricky than creating one, thats why i suggested it. However i want to thank you for your time and effort for this post. Your ideas have been placed under consideration

Comment: This question appears to be generating some really off topic discussions and bad answers

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with a physical machine - If you're running your OS as a VM you can take advantage of [live migration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_migration) to do something *very* similar to what you're describing.

I know you can pass through a video card with the right hardware - (puget systems has great writeups on two different configurations - [KVM on ubuntu with nvidia cards](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/) and [ESXi](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multi-headed-VMWare-Gaming-Setup-564/)) but I have no idea how this would react to a hot, live migration - I suspect horrible things would happen between dissimilar hardware. You can then store your OS on NAS, maybe with 10Gb Ethernet connecting the systems (gig-e might be a bottleneck here) so you can 'switch' between systems.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply and Ideas that was Quite Usefull :)

Comment: This is not a solution either. What exactly would be the point of a virtualizing this computer? Sounds like a good way to take a superb PC and turn it into an average at best PC (with only basic hardware support). Throw out any plans you ever had of utilizing that $4k video card, lets just use the generic emulated version which came with our VM software. No, virtualization is the opposite of what you want.

Comment: You can passthrough the video card *directly* to a VM with the *right* hardware with VT-D and the right hypervisor. I'm just unsure whether it'll work *with* live migration. You won't be using the emulated video card. I just wonder how a VM would react to going to sleep and waking up with a different GPU

Comment: https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotos09/tech/full_papers/kozuch/kozuch_html/index.html

Answer (score -1):

Wow, no, this isn't realistic at all. First of all, really consider if you need a computer that powerful. Top of the line parts, such as 4 titans are not 'bang for your buck' parts, they are very fast, but you pay a premium for them. It makes much more financial sense to get maybe slightly older high-end hardware.

Second, what is the goal of the computer? Gaming? Video rendering? Cryptocurrency mining? You have an amalgamation of types of hardware which don't really make sense together. 4 Titans are great for gaming, but a Quatro and Tesla are for scientific computation, and they are optimized for such, so pick your cards accordingly.

Next, because you are using drastically different hardware, you can't just copy RAM from one system to another, there are a ton of underlying issues with the state of the machine that you can't predict or handle, such was what data is in the processor cache or what the CPU registers are set to. Next, the bootup procedure in any operating system doesn't let you just start immediately reading RAM and even if you could, how would it know what RAM to read first, that data is stored in the processor, and you can't pull that out and send it to your new computer.

What you're asking to do is not just infeasible, it's impossible considering how complex computers are at this point. This just isn't going to happen whether you are an electrical engineer, computer scientist, processor designer, or all three.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply. In my Topic i said that the Software will take care everything of modifing the kernel to believe its in the right place. Please do check my comments on the previous Answer of my Question and keep in mind that nothing is Impossible. You can manipulate every Computer's part to do whatever you want.

P.S the Second Setup is for a Scientist & Mechanic

Comment: Oh sounds like you have it covered, go for it then.

Comment: There are many factors that we have to cover in order to achieve that many values to change in each switch many processing time, whatsoever it is possible. Everything is possible when you are aware of the architecture of a machine. The target of my Question was not to check if that is possible, but to see if any of you have a better idea than that.

Comment: Your idea isn't going to work with windows or Linux which means your own kernel which means every piece of software would have to be ported to this horrible franksentien OS